Recommending a pre-train NER model for geospatial entities
I am trying to find the best pre-trained Hugging Face Transformer model exclusively dedicated to geospatial or location entities to extract location entities in English from a text. Does it work way better than roberta-large?

If you want to best NER model then you can try llama 3.1 8b instruct 4 bit quantise model. I have tried it on various different types of example and in almost every case it was able to identify the Geo spatial entities. And Llama is also a transformer based model. and it is far better then Bert/Roberta based model.
Hugging face model: https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct
Note: Final output can be structured as you need by post processing logic and prompting.
I have tested it on my own deployed model:

